# How can I create a custom TypeScript Declaration library and import them into my projects via NPM/Github Packages?

Tags: typescript, npm, types, typescript-typings, typescript-declarations

**Overview**

I'm building and publishing a custom TypeScript type declaration library to be used across my projects. I'm having an issue with importing the TypeScript library into my projects. It imports, but I keep getting the error: `Module not found`.

**What I've tried**

- I've tried modifying the `package.json`
- I've tried modifying the `tsonfig.json`
- I've exported the `type` and `interface` from `src/types/locationTypes.ts`

**src/types/locationTypes.ts**

```js
// TypeScript Type: Latitude
export type TLatitude = number;

// TypeScript Type: TLongitude
export type TLongitude = number;

// TypeScript Type: Coordinates
export interface ICoordinates {
  latitude: TLatitude;
  longitude: TLongitude;
}
```

**src/index.ts**

```js
// Imports: TypeScript Types
import * as dateTypes from './types/dateTypes';
import * as locationTypes from './types/locationTypes';

// Exports
export {
  dateTypes,
  locationTypes,
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@username/custom-types",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./dist/index.ts",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "description": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/username/custom-types.git"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/username"
  },
  "author": "Jeff Lewis",
  "license": "MIT",
  "keywords": [
    "typescript",
    "types",
    "component-library",
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cd src && tsc && cp ../package.json && Echo Build completed!",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.29.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.4"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "include": ["src/*"],                                                   // Specifies an array of filenames or patterns to include in the program
  "exclude": [                                                            // Specifies an array of filenames or patterns that should be skipped when resolving include. It is not a mechanism that prevents a file from being included in the codebase - it simply changes what the include setting finds.
    "**/__tests__/*",
    "node_modules",
    "babel.config.js",
    "metro.config.js",
    "jest.config.js",
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module":  "ES6",                                                     // Sets the module system for the program. (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)
    "outDir": "./dist",                                                   // If specified, .js (as well as .d.ts, .js.map, etc.) files will be emitted into this directory. The directory structure of the original source files is preserved
    "declaration": true,                                                  // Generate .d.ts files for every TypeScript or JavaScript file inside your project.
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,                                          // Only emit .d.ts files; Does not emit for .js files. (For TypeScript type definition libraries only?)
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./dist/index.d.ts"],          // If typeRoots is specified, only packages under typeRoots will be included.
    "strict": true,                                                       // Enable all strict type-checking options.
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,                                          // Enable strict checking of function types.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your `src/index.ts` should be:

```
export * from'./types/dateTypes';
export * from './types/locationTypes';
```